# what is difference between Java script and c#?

Tags: .net

I have some doubt on that can u please give answer for that ? Java script no need compiler but for c# we need compiler to run.Please give answer for above question ?

Comment: Serverfault isn't the forum for software development questions. Take a look at Stackoverflow. You may get a fairly frostly response on there also as the answer to your question is readily available via search engines, plus your question is too generic.

Answer (score 2):

Although C# and Javascript can both be used for similar purposes (web development for instance) There are considerable differences between both languages. The primary ones being that although both require a form of interpreter to run, C# is compiled into what we call byte code (similar to java) and javascript is interpreted by a javascript engine (traditionally web browsers). The differences are vast from here and I would recommend that in order for you to get a more complete answer that you re-ask the question in the programmers community of stack overflow.